# How to force LinearModelFit to return Non-negative coefficients?

Tags: fitting, constraint

`LinearModelFit[{m,v}]` will return a coefficients list $\beta$ from the design matrix $m$ and response vector $v$, where $m.\beta$ is fitted to $v$. However, the parameters in $\beta$ could be negative. For example,

```
LinearModelFit[{{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 7, 6}}, {2, 3}}]["BestFitParameters"]
```

will return `{0.0381679, 0.198473, -0.00763359, 0.396947}`, where the third parameter is negative.

How could I force `LinearModelFit[{m,v}]` to fit with only positive parameters? Is there an Option I can set constrain on coefficients?

---

I use `LinearModelFit[{m,v}]` because the length of $m$ (the number of variable) could vary from case to case.

---

Seems I raise a bad example. In reality the number of unknowns is less than the number of equations, that is `Length@m[[1]]<Length@v`.

Comment: An easy yet inefficient route: `NonlinearModelFit[Append @@@ Transpose[{{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 7, 6}}, {2, 3}}], {Array[c, 4].Array[x, 4], And @@ Thread[Array[c, 4] > 0]}, Array[c, 4], Array[x, 4]]`

Comment: something like Array[x, 4] could be used as four variables..OMG....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this picture:
[image]

What would the best approximation to "vec" be, when the condition: "y component of vec is zero" is imposed? The best approx. under this condition is setting the y component to zero.

Back to your question. You simply need to set the negative component to zero.

Comment: This is genius....wait...suppose the formula is $C_x x+C_y y$, if now $C_y$ is setted to 0 from negative value, shouldn't $C_x$ decrease a bit to balance (given xs, ys are all positive) and achieve better fitting?

Comment: The picture is illuminating....but is somewhere a proof make sure "set the negative component to zero" gives the best approx? seems it makes a vector closest to the solution with no constrain....emmm....

Comment: Think about it this way: you are searching a vector vec1 so that the distance vec1-vec is minimal. In the above example this vector is the projection of vec on the x axis.In the general case, it is the projection to the subspace with y=0

Comment: `NMinimize` evaluates a much better solution than the projective one: `NMinimize[{#.# &[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 7, 6}}.{b1, b2, b3, b4} - {2, 
     3}], b1 > 0, b2 > 0, b3 > 0, b4 > 0}, {b1, b2, b3, b4}] (*{3.35725*10^-9, {b1 -> 0.000104177, b2 -> 0.502257, 
  b3 -> 0.0000209469, b4 -> 0.248818}}*)`

Comment: You are partially right. The main problem is that we have 4 unknowns and only 2 equations. Therefore, there are an infinity of solutions. the simplest one would be: {0,1,0,0}.  Now, what I did is to approximate the vector: {0.0381679, 0.198473, -0.00763359, 0.396947} as well as possible with positive coefficients. Now, the question arise why neither LinearModelFit nor NMinimize gives a correct result. I can only guess that numerical errors with real numbers are the reason.

Comment: emmm....minimal distance doesn't necessarily mean best vector...the error landscape might not be spherical symmetry....but it might be good enough...

Comment: Well, what would you suggest what "best" should mean?

Comment: minimize the error, I mean, if number of equations is larger than the number of unknowns...@DanielHuber